# Additional button in Yii2 form submits the form instead of calling its action

Tags: php, forms, yii, yii2

I have a typical Yii2 form for updating my model with a typical submit button. Next to it, I have a "*Delete photo*" button, that appears, if there is any photo to delete. The piece of view looks like that:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Save changes', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'edit-button']) ?>

<?php $image = isset($page->photo) ? $page->photo->getImageUrl() : null; ?>

<?php if (isset($image)): ?>

    <?= Html::a('Delete photo', ['delete-image', 'lab' => $lab->id, 'kind' => $page->kind], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Do you really want to delete this photo?',
            'method' => 'post'
        ],
    ]) ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

When there is a photo attached to this model and these two buttons appear next to each other, I must comment out `'method' => 'post'` part in second button code. Because, if I don't this this, the second button is... submitting the form (just like the first one) instead of calling `lab/delete-image` route.

This is the first thing, that I don't understand. The entire code is either generated by Gii or copy-pasted from some Yii tutorials. Not even a bit of my invention and yet it works strangely. What am I missing?

**It seems, that normal `Html::a` link** (only styled by Twitter Bootstrap to look like a button, but not being a button at all) **is submitting a form, instead of calling its action, when it contains `data-method="post"` attribute in element code**. Is this a bug in Yii2 or am I missing something?

Comment: I have removed second part of this question, because it was a result of concept misunderstanding / simple typo. VerbFilter should use `delete-image` as action name, not `deleteImage` for dual word action names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to place the link outside of the form. For calling actions from elements with `data-method` attribute yii has js function `handleAction`, and its documentation says:

> This method recognizes the `data-method` attribute of the element. If the attribute exists, the method will submit the form containing this element. If there is no containing form, a form will be created and submitted using the method given by this attribute value (e.g. "post", "put").
>
> For hyperlinks, the form action will take the value of the "href" attribute of the link.

Also if you use yii2 v2.0.3 or higher you can add `data-params` attribute which value should be JSON representation of the data, and this data will be submitted in request. As example:

```
 echo Html::a('Delete image', ['delete-image'], [
     'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Do you really want to delete this photo?'
        'method' => 'post',
        'params' => [
            'lab' => $lab->id,
            'kind' => $page->kind,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

In this example `params` array will be json encoded by yii2 internaly

Comment: Can you provide any example for having mentioned "_Delete image_" button in alternate way (with `data-params`)?

Comment: @trejder added example

Comment: @Tony and trejder : How to use this please explain?